# Mapping simple array - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to map a simple array in reactjs, but this is not working.

As array contains values.

```
<select className="mobile">
  {
    departments.map((number) =>{
      return (<option>{number}</option>)
    })
  }
</select>
```

> But select box is empty.

Here is console log of departments.

[image]

Here is where departments are being filled:

```
  getAllDepartments(){
      db.collection('companies').doc(currentUserData.company_id).collection('departments').get().then(function(compSnapshot){
        console.log(compSnapshot.size + "   ---- SIZE");
        compSnapshot.forEach(compDoc => {
          departments.push(compDoc.data().deptname);
        })
      })
  }
```

NOTE: departments are being filled (for sure) before component is being rendered.

Comment: what does `does not work mean`. Is there an error.

Comment: Select box do not get populated, as mentioned in question. It remains empty. But it is supposed to be filled with 5 values.

Comment: Can you post the full code? Specifically, where `departments` is being defined.

Comment: Posted @RafaelQuintanilha

Comment: and Where is component reading this departments array from. getAllDepartments isn't returning it

Comment: And where `getAllDepartments` is being called and `departments` is being defined? You might want to set `departments` as a state of your component and then call `this.setState` when the array arrives.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Rafael Please check this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/iz3uwhqb

Comment: where do you add the code to map over the department in your Pastebin implementation

Comment: Extremely sorry @ShubhamKhatri, i did changed for testing purpose. Here it is: https://pastebin.com/TDW0i7T0